# Pocket IE throws ODBC error but desktop browsers do not

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, mobile

I have a fairly simple CRUD web application (C#/ASP.NET) that runs fine in Firefox, IE7, and Chrome. (I'm accessing and testing the application on our development server.)

When I connect to the dev site via a Pocket PC device and go through the exact same steps, I get an ODBC error. Unfortunately, when I step through the code (once again, on my desktop) I can't duplicate the error. Same environment, different browser. All the code is server side, so I can't figure out why I'm getting different results.

I've run through the code with the Pocket PC emulator and it works fine. It only happens when I access the site via the actual device. I have similar pages, accessing the same ODBC database that don't have this problem on the Pocket PC device.

Anyone ever seen something like this? I'm stumped.

Edit: Here's the text of the ODBC error. The error code '38121' refers to an invalid order number, even though I know for sure that the order number is not invalid. (I'm using the same order number on my desktop as I am on the handheld.) If needed, I can post the stack track too.

****ERROR [HY000] [CA][IDMS ODBC Driver][IDMS]DB001075 C-4M321: Procedure LOEPU041 exception 38121 ?**

Double edit: Chalk it up to user error. The database requires all parameters to be entered in uppercase. On my machine I was used to entering the order number in all uppercase. Since the Pocket PC has a crappy keyboard, I would always just enter it in lowercase. A simple ToUpper() fixed it. Holy crap, I feel dumb.

Comment: And the text of the ODBC error is?

Comment: "I have similar pages ... that don't have this problem" means you'll have to be a lot more specific about the page that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the values are submitted as you
  expect them in the request handler
- Check the values are passed to the
  database statements correctly
- Implement server-side error logging /
  tracing
- Memorize the text of the error
  message(s)

Comment: Chalk it up to user error. The database requires all parameters to be entered in uppercase. On my machine I was used to entering the order number in all uppercase. Since the Pocket PC has a crappy keyboard, I would always just enter it in lowercase. A simple ToUpper() fixed it. Holy crap, I feel dumb. Thanks for making me double check the values passed to the database! :)